# Standardized python binary location?

Tags: python

On a native `Mac OS X` install, I see `Python` binary at `/usr/bin` at version `2.6`

Recently I installed `Python 2.7.2` from the official binaries and it installed it at `/usr/local/bin`

What path of the `Python` interpreter should I give in my `#!` which will be standardized across all platforms?

I am assuming it could be `/usr/bin` so that I may have to symlink `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/local/bin/python` but I just wanted to sure before I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You would use `env` to find the `python` executable in `$PATH` and run it as appropriate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print 'Hi mom!'
```

Comment: But first you have to have the right directory on your PATH.  For OS X Python framework installs, that's not necessarily obvious.  `/usr/local/bin` isn't sufficient when you install third-party packages with scripts.  You need to include the framework `bin` directory; various distributors of OS X Pythons use different locations for their framework roots.

Comment: Evangelize the python3!! `print('Hi Mum!')`

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, do not modify anything in `/usr` (including `/usr/bin`) other than `/usr/local`, nor anything in `/System/Library`.  Those directory spaces are managed by Apple as part of OS X.  You risk breaking your system if you change or delete the wrong thing there.  The best way to manage different versions is to modify your shell `PATH` environment variable; then you can use `/usr/bin/env` if needed.  You can also use shell aliases or just use absolute paths.  The Python installers from python.org have an option to automatically modify your shell initialization files appropriately.